# FullCalendar date & time Format

Tags: calendar, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

1.In Events **start date :2015-02-09, end date: 2015-02-13,**

but calendar view **9th date to 12th date** only...

**How to Fix this issue?**

2.I need **dd-mm-yyyy** date Format.. i don't need to Time..

How to fix this?

**Pls Need Your Help?**

Code :

```
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({


               header: {
                    left: 'prev,next',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                firstDay: 0,
                editable: false,
                droppable: false,

                events: [


                    {
                        title: 'Live Conference',
                        start: '2015-02-09',
                        end: '2015-02-13',
                    }, {
                        title: 'Top Secret Project',
                        start: '2015-02-14',
                        end: '2015-02-16',
                        color: '#1abc9c'
                    },

                    {
                        title: 'Free Pizza',
                        description: 'This is just a fake description for the Free Pizza.Nothing to see!',
                        start: '2015-02-14',
                        end: '2015-02-16',

                    }, {
                        title: 'Free Pizza 2',
                        description: 'This is sdfsfption for the Free Pizza.Nothing to see!',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 17),
                        end: new Date(y, m, 19),

                    }

                ],


                eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {

                    $('#editevent').modal('show');
                    $('#modalTitle').val(event.title);
                    $('#modalStartDate').val(event.start);
                    $('#modalEndDate').val(event.end);
                    $('#modalBody').val(event.description);
                    //$('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);

                }

            });
```

Comment: please improve your question.  What have you tried so far ?

Comment: thanks for response .. i need to get start & end date in this dd-mm-yyyy format...

Comment: I understood what you are asking for but StackOverflow is a site where you post questions about a problem you are having, not a list of requirements expecting others to do your work. So have you tried to solve this yourself and ran into a problem? What error did you get?

Comment: @aberna  thank u for quick Response..      In events : title: 'Live Conference',
                        start: '2015-02-09',
                        end: '2015-02-13',    but calendar display like this http://s21.postimg.org/wzul2spdj/image.png

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using fullcalendar 1.x. Make sure you upgrade at least to 1.6.4
After that set `timezone`to local:

```
$('#calendar').fullcalendar({
    ...
    timezone: 'local',
    ...
});
```

See this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/wLuj3fzv/

Since version 2.0 of fullcalendar it is integrated with momentJS. It provides a really nice interface for date object creation and manipulation. I would recommend to use that if this is possible in your project.